# Safari window.open() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, safari, window.open

I need to open external link in a new window. I handle click on edit button in a view:

```
module.exports = utils.Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click #edit": "onEditClicked"
    },

    "onEditClicked": () => PubSub.publish("EDITOR_REQUESTED");
});
```

Then I check if the user is logged in. 
If yes - I send notification "OPEN_EDITOR" and expect a new window to be open with the external link.

```
TextEditorController.prototype.handleMessages = function () {

    PubSub.subscribe("OPEN_EDITOR", () => {
        var editor = window.open(this.$service.getEditorURL());
    });
});
```

But in Safari new window seems to be blocked? Is there workaround in my case?

Answer (score 17):

The reason of it is Safari's built-in pop-up blockers.

The only javascript that is allowed to open a new window in Safari - is javascript directly attached to user's event. In your case, you're calling window.open later.

The workaround here can be:

- to create a window without a URL in onEditClicked method

  `safariWindow = window.open();`
- change that window's URL in handleMessages function

  `safariWindow.location.href = newUrl`

Comment: I just built a system that uses popups for people. And while it works for everyone else, safari users would have issues with the popups not working. Once I found this answer, I understand that it has to be a user's "event" in order for it to work in safari. Now I can adjust my code to work with safari browsers so popups work properly for those users. But man, what a pain it was trying to figure this out, until I found this answer! :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to open a popup window in the Safari browser, you need to follow the below code.
Open popup window before getting URL from the backend.

```
const width = 500;
const height = 600;
const top = window.innerHeight / 2 - height / 2;
const left = window.innerWidth / 2 - width / 2;
const params = `modal=yes, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=${width}, height=${height}, top=${top}, left=${left}`;
if (oauthPopup === null || oauthPopup.closed) {
  console.log(oauthPopup);
  oauthPopup = window.open("", "", params);
}
```

After getting a URL from the backend, change the location of the popup window.

```
await request()
  .get(`/sources/authorizationEndpoint`, {
    headers: {
      authorizer: token,
    },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    const url = response.data.oauth_url;
    oauthPopup.location = url;
    oauthPopup.focus();       
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    oauthPopup.close();
  });
```