# URL Link to redirect to App Store download

Tags: ios, reactjs

I'm creating a Reactjs website to redirect user to the App Store automatically after they scan the QR code. It works on browser, however it does not work on iOS device safari. Here's the code

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  openNewWindow() {
    window.open("https://apps.apple.com/us/app/google-maps-transit-food/id585027354", "_blank") //to open new page

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.open("https://apps.apple.com/us/app/google-maps-transit-food/id585027354", "_blank") //to open new page
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-default pull-right"
        onClick={this.openNewWindow}
      >
        Open Another Window
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Another issue is how do I close the current tab after redirecting to App Store app?

The behaviour is similar to what is offered by [onelink](https://apps.apple.com/)

Comment: I believe this is related to the way Safari handles popup blocking. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362093/safari-window-open-doesnt-work

Comment: @JeffJ could you please give an example? Couldn't comprehend this "The only javascript that is allowed to open a new window in Safari - is javascript directly attached to user's event. In your case, you're calling window.open later.
"

Comment: Instead of calling this.openNewWindow in your onClick, put your window.open call there directly and test. I believe that will work in Safari.

Comment: Directly means? I have it in componentDidMount as well just wondering why isn't it called? And the one in onClick works, however, I would like it to have an automatic redirect without user intervention

Comment: The key with Safari and window.open is that Safari requires is be directly tied to a user interaction.  So onclick="myfunction()" (where myfunction() runs window.open) will not work. The window.open must be directly called from the user interaction (button onclick event).  As far as automatic redirect you will have the same problem. You might try location.assign("yoururlhere") to redirect the current tab/window, but opening a new window with no user interaction (click, etc) will likely be blocked by popup blocking.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! managed to get it to work with window.location.assign("url"). One more thing , how can I close the current window after redirecting to the App Store? This behaviour is exhibited by onelink